# OpenCV + visualStudio , C++ code error trying to access pixels

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm Joe and I'm a new member of this site.
Let's go to the point...I start programming in c++ with openCV libraries on visual studio but I have a question about image's pixels..
I wrote a code to calculate the average of the alpha channel (the foruth component of a pixel, in addition to B,G,R intensity's values)..
enter image description here
I fall into an error and I don't know how to fix it. 
Here's my code

```
      #include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Mat image;
    image = imread("C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/prova/paesaggioLuminoso.jpg", 1);
    namedWindow("Picture", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
    imshow("Picture", image);
    waitKey(0);

    int averageAlpha = 0;
    int partial = 0;



    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++) {



            partial = partial +image.at<Vec4b>(i, j)[3];



            if (i == image.rows - 1 && j == image.cols - 1) {
                averageAlpha = partial / (image.rows * image.cols);

                cout << "Average of alpha channel is " << averageAlpha << endl;

            }

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that if I try to calculate average of B intensity (or Green or red) , my program runs correctly .

But with this fourth channel I have this error message:
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC47603FB8 in Secondo Progetto OpenCV.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000162E2FF3E0.

Assertion failed ((unsigned)(i1 * DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CJ28.png) * channels())) in cv::Mat::at,  file c:\users\joe\desktop\joe\opencv\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp, line 1095

Thanks for the help ! Have a good day !

EDIT: here's the error I mentioned in the comment

[Errors in visual studio with a correct code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CJ28.png)

[Other errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5ZFq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78hna.png)

Comment: "I wrote a code to calculate the average" -- reinventing [`cv::mean`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga191389f8a0e58180bb13a727782cd461)?

Comment: ups :))  sorry but i'm still a newbie of coding!

Comment: More of a reason to familiarize yourself with the OpenCV documentation and get a gist of what sort of functionality is available and where to look for info. ;)

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate your help and your mindset ! Maybe do you know why sometimes visual studio gives me error with the same (the same!) codes that five minutes before worked correctly? :)

Comment: What sort of an error? I can't imagine how a compile error could appear in that situation, so I guess it's a runtime error -- that's quite possible if there are bugs in your code. However, without a concrete example, it's impossible to say what exactly the cause is. When it happens next time, post a question with all the details.

Comment: Sorry @DanMašek you're right...here are the errors I was talking about ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CJ28.png

Comment: @Joe looks to me like you opened a opencv internal header and accidentally deleted something. I think `typname` is supposed to be `typename`. I'd say just re-install opencv

Comment: I solved it with a re-installation...many thanks man, your advices are so helpful !

Answer (score 0):

You're passing as flag '1' which equals IMREAD_COLOR see this: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgcodecs/include/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp

And IMREAD_COLOR drops the alpha channel, see this
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80

so you should be doing

```
image = imread("C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/prova/paesaggioLuminoso.jpg", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
```

Comment: many thanks ! I want to try your line of code but now I have a new problem, don't know why, my visual studio doesn't compile anymore. I have this:    error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'typname',  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int and other errors..
Don't know why..an hour ago my codes worked, now not anymore! :(

Comment: @Joe try passing -1 instead of IMREAD_UNCHANGED.

Comment: thank you very much ; I tried in the two ways you suggested (both IMREAD_UNCHANGED and -1 ) but I fall into these errors:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/78hna.png

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5ZFq.png

Comment: @Joe try printing the number of channels, after the imshow put cout << image.channels() << endl;

Comment: Ooh thanks @Aram : the number of channels is 3. Now I understand...many thanks !

Comment: @Joe You're welcome. Btw I googled around a bit and it seems jpg does not support an alpha channel thats why you only have 3 channels, even with IMREAD_UNCHANGED, irrespective of that your code shouldn't depend on having or not having, an alpha channel.